# Django Search not working for Project 1 need code

Tags: python, django

I have a code to have a search box do the following:

Search: Allow the user to type a query into the search box in the sidebar to search for an encyclopedia entry.
If the query matches the name of an encyclopedia entry, the user should be redirected to that entry’s page.
If the query does not match the name of an encyclopedia entry, the user should instead be taken to a search results page that displays a list of all encyclopedia entries that have the query as a substring. For example, if the search query were Py, then Python should appear in the search results.
Clicking on any of the entry names on the search results page should take the user to that entry’s page.

this is the code I have:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from . import util
from django.urls import reverse

def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })
    
def wiki(request, title):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/wiki.html", {
        "entries": util.get_entry(title)
    })
    
def search(request): 
    entries = util.list_entries()
    query = request.session['query']
    find_entries = list()

    search_box = request.POST.get("q", "").capitalize()

    if search_box in entries:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"wiki/{search_box}")
        
    for entry in entries:
        if re.search(query, entry):
            find_entries.append(entry)
       
        
    if find_entries:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
          "search_result": find_entries,
          "search": search_box
    })
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.wiki, name="wiki"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
]
```

I am getting this error:

UPDATED ERRROR: KeyError at /search
'query'

util.py ( i dont have a settings.py)

```
import re

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage


def list_entries():
    """
    Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
    """
    _, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))


def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))


def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

Please help

Comment: Could you post what is inside the `middleware` variable on your `settings.py`?
And did you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Did you create and apply all migrations?

Comment: @JônatasCastro after i did this i now get this error: KeyError at /search
'query'

Answer (score 0):

Run makemigrations and migrate. If it doesnt work, delete migrations and run makemigations and migrate again

Answer (score -1):

you didn't import re, try that and it should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).